# Background Elixir process in Phoenix app failing in Cloud Run

Tags: http, elixir, google-cloud-run

I'm experiencing a terrible performance when a deploy my Phoenix app in Cloud Run with 'background' processes, and I will be more specific.

I have an Elixir 'Synker' module that, for the sake of conciseness, simply does an HTTP get to a site.

This module works perfectly if I call it from an endpoint and the request is done in less than 1 second.

But I want to call this module every 5 minutes, so I have a `GenServer` with a `Process.send_after` configured to do so.

The problem is when the process fires and calls the 'Synker', this HTTP get requests takes muuuuuuch longer, around 30 seconds.

Why this difference?? Does this ring any bell?

In practice I need to do multiple requests and they fail

Answer (score 1):

Well, I moved it to App Engine and there it works as expected. So, be careful if you do async HTTP request in Cloud Run out of a HTTP request to your service (maybe this is documented somewhere).

Comment: Perhaps [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-tasks) and [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler) to trigger a Cloud Run service would've been useful to you.

Comment: That's right, but I prefer not to depend on other external tools

Comment: It is indeed documented. You are not supposed to do background processing in Cloud Run  after a request is completed. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#avoiding_background_activities